# How to get the current collectionview cell size in swift2?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I am not like to get the cell size inside cell for row at indexpath
Please anybody help me to get the cell size.

**UICollectionView** **IBOutlet** name is **collectionData**;

Comment: While cellForItemAtIndexPath defines how the cell will be, I don't think that is right place to get cell size. while you can retrieve it with cell.frame.size

Comment: @Arvind i need storyboard cell size values is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by current cell? Any given cell in the collection view or what?? Please be clear in your question.

Comment: @satheeshwaran in storyboard cell is there i need that size before entering into cell for row at indexpath

Comment: @Kishorekumar Dude that is okay, but you cannot get the cell size before even it has initialized. What do you want to do, tell me I will help you.

Answer (score 2):

UICollectionView is data driven, like all iOS GUI classes. Which means - you do not ask the collection view for the cell size but you *tell* the collection view the cell size. So, where did you tell the collection view the cell size? In the storyboard, programatically in the layout? Or in a delegate func? There you have it - your cell size.